# How to display the category tree on the left sidebar on one particular CMS page?

Tags: magento2, layout, cms-pages

**Magento 2.4**

I tried displaying the category tree on the left sidebar on one of my CMS pages. The url key / identifier is `mypage.html`. I already set the layout to be 2 columns with left sidebar.

Now I figured that I have to create a XML file with a certain name pattern, but I did not manage to do so, maybe because of the .html in the url key / identifier? So, how must I call my XML layout update file, where do I have to place it and would that content be correct?

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml" />
    </reference>
</page>
```

Thanks!